# how do I determinethe end device-screen size for a webpage?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive design for a webpage and found css such as
this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: xpx) {
```

The problem I am facing is that mobile devices have higher and higher display resolutions and it can be very challanging to determine if this is a high resolution small screen or a low resolution large screen.

Additionally I might not want my webpage to change to mobile layout if the user decides to use only one half of the screen for the webpage on a desktop.

How can I adjust my css so that I have a proper large screen and small screen layout possibly without applying fixed-pixel values?

Answer (score 2):

The whole topic of responsive web design is way more difficult than you think. There is a difference between `physical pixel` (hardware pixel) and `CSS pixel` (software pixel).

Most of mobile high-resolution screens have a ratio of 2:1 (hardware:software pixel). YOu can disable that default behavior with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. However, you should not as it exists for a reason.

Another mostly reliable method of recognizing mobile devices is to check if the screen is a touchscreen. However, it there are many laptops or other PC's with touchscreens (Surfaces e.g.).

A good list of possible touch devices is this:

```css
/* smartphones, touchscreens */
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  ...
}

/* Screens with Pen support such as Stylus */
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: fine) {
  ...
}

/* Controller such as gaming controller or Wii / Switch */
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: coarse) {
  ...
}

/* mouse, touchpad */
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  ...
}
```